# Integrate and execute protractor e2e automated tests in VSTS/TFS Continuous integration

Tags: continuous-integration, protractor, automated-tests

Is it possible to Integrate and execute protractor e2e automated tests in VSTS/TFS Continuous integration? If possible please explain the process/steps?

Comment: look how you execute it right now. check the parameter passed, commands executed. You can use the same command with same parameters to execute your tests.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with with Visual Studio & Team Foundation Server but the below steps should suffice to guide you

1. Create a build process in TFS with Grunt as task runner or Just configure a batch file utility for the sake of simplicity [Configuring Batch File as build definition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/batch-script)
2. Configure your git repository
3. Add a trigger - May be another build or external trigger
4. Configure the below bat file(Or create a grunt task for more professional handling) into build definition

> ```
> echo Protractor Execution %AGENT_NAME%.
> Protractor protractor.conf.js
> echo Over and out.
> ```

More details @ [TFS Build Configuration](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/build)

Comment: the problem is that protractor uses ChromeDriver to launch a chrome browser instance, and ChromeDriver is not installed on vsts

Comment: if you are using an in-house build agent, then you could install chrome and run the file. If you have a grunt or similar task runner, then there are also grunt build tasks that could execute a gruntfile.js and the related e2e commands. 
Chrome doesn't auto exit so make sure you kill it after the execution. 
Get-Process chromedriver* -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Stop-Process -PassThru -Force

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute your e2e tests you have to start your application and run the command "protractor" in parallel. If your are using .NET Core the command to start your application would be "dotnet run". To run the commands "dotnet run" and "protractor" in parallel you can use the npm package concurrently.

Add the following lines to the scripts in your package.json file:

```
"pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
"e2e": "concurrently --success first --kill-others \"dotnet run\"  \"protractor\" "
```

You should now be able to execute your e2e tests with the command "npm run e2e". This will first execute the pree2e script. Afterwards it will start your server and parallely try to run your protractor tests. Running the tests can only succeed as soon as your server is running, so make sure the timeouts in your protractor config file are long enough (for me 60 000 ms for the getPageTimeout and 60 000 ms for the defaultTimeoutInterval in the jasmineNodeOpts worked). The command will finish as soon as protractor finishes its tests.

If this works for you locally you can add a npm build step in your VSTS/TFS. Insert "run" for npm command and "e2e" for arguments. Your e2e tests should now run whenever you trigger the build. However, if you are using the hosted build agent in VSTS you will not be able to use any normal browsers like Chrome or Firefox. It might work with PhantomJS but the usage of PhantomJS with protractor is not recommended in the [protractor documentation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md).